# Linear span of p = 1 and q = (x-1)^2

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the linear span obtained with these two polynomials :

$$p = 1$$

$$q = (x-1)^2$$

Where $p,q$ lives in $\Pi^2$, i.e. $\mathbb R^2[x]$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Simply calling it "the linear span of $p$ and $q$" is usually sufficient.  What more do you want?

Comment: I have a question in my homework and it says "Caracterise the linear span of p and q". I think we need to "detail" what the linear span of p and q is ...

Comment: You could describe it as the span of two different polynomials if you wanted... but what makes the one representation "more convenient" than another is completely personal preference.  Equivalently, you could describe a relationship between $a,b,c$ that must be satisfied for a polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ to be in the span (*but again, this is equivalent to simply describing it by a different basis*).

Comment: In that case, $a$ and $b$ must have something in common, can you see what must be true about the relationship between $a$ and $b$?  You will have that $c$ can be anything.

Comment: Well, I find that A(0,0,1) + B(1,-2,1) = Bx^2 - 2Bx + (A+B). Is that what you mean?

Comment: And if you call $(A+B)$ something else, say,,, $C$, you have the linear span of $\{1,(x-1)^2\}$ is equal to the linear span of $\{1,x^2-2x\}$ is the set of polynomials $\{ax^2+bx+c~:~b=-2a\}$.  Again, all three representations are equivalent and which is preferred is personal preference.

Comment: Ok, a big thank you. I was wondering if it was *more* difficult than that. I was worried for nothing I guess. A big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want
$$
\alpha 1+\beta(x-1)^2, \ \ \ \ \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R.
$$

Comment: Is that simple ?

Comment: That's what the span is. You can start playing with algebra if you want, and write $\alpha+\beta-2\beta x+\beta x^2$, if you want it to look a little more complicated.

Comment: No, it's ok like that. Thank you for your time.